# autosys doesn't run batch file

Tags: batch-file, autosys

i wrote a batch file to open a webrowser, then close it, then open another and close it. upon opening the browser it will send email out. when i manually run the batch it works, but when i use autosys to run it, email never got sent. here's the batch file:

```
@echo off
start iexplore.exe http://localhost/licensedb/Dev/home.php
ping 123.45.67.89 -n 1 -w 20000 > nul
taskkill /im iexplore.exe
start iexplore.exe http://localhost/licensedb/Dev/send_mail.php
ping 123.45.67.89 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
taskkill /im iexplore.exe
```

Here's the autosys command line:

```
insert_job: cots_license_tracker   job_type: c 
command: "D\:\Application Tracking\text.bat"
machine: computer name
owner: serviceautosys@domain
permission: 
date_conditions: 1
run_calendar: Bi-weekly_Mondays
start_times: "09:00"
std_out_file: D\:\logs\AutoSys\sys\%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.out
std_err_file: D\:\logs\AutoSys\sys\%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.err
alarm_if_fail: 0
```

Sorry if I asked in the wrong place... first time posting here

Comment: Does Autosys use a special syntax for specifying drive letters in paths? I mean, is this path correct: `D\:\Application Tracking\text.bat`? Typically you'd have it simply like `D:\Application Tracking\text.bat` (no backslash before the colon).

Comment: double check the \ after D "D\:..." Example: command: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C copy C:\env.txt C:\test\env.txt"

Answer (score 0):

When defining the command in Autosys, you should either use double quotes around the entire command *or* escape special characters. You are doing both here - you probably need to use double quotes around everything since there is a space in your command, so try removing the escape character before the colon.